# Why is following a question available only via RSS?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

**Shouldn't the devs eventually add the option to allow following a question via email**, as [Quora](http://www.quora.com/) and [Github](https://github.com/) do?

I'd rather be emailed about new answers to a question I am interested in. I know I can have RSS come into my email client (Outlook), but I don't really use RSS for keeping up with stuff. Never got into it. Maybe Google is right, it's [time to retire RSS](http://pandodaily.com/2013/04/29/lets-retire-rss-when-they-retire-google-reader-2/)?

It is great to be able to bookmark a question, as currently available. But following a question, without having to rely on RSS, is also useful. Each option clearly has its place: on Quora they can't simply bookmark a question without following it, and that has been [causing problems for some of their users](http://studyingquora.quora.com/Quora-881-Notifications-and-Why-Following-Questions-Doesnt-Work).

In Github, *watching still allows them to get notifications for projects all the same, but now users had a new recourse to simply bookmark interesting projects.*. Originally, only follow existed, they later added the option to simply bookmark a project.

[image]

**Both Quora and Github notify users who follow a question via email.** Why won't Stack Exchange do it?

Comment: Quora is designed as addition to social networks (Twitter, Facebook), GitHub is designated as "social coding" site...Stack Exchange is about questions getting answers (notice that missing buzzword "social"). Not that your request is invalid or something (just a dupe), but that's an important difference you should keep in mind when comparing such sites to Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Google isn't retiring RSS, just their reader. Just because you never got into it, doesn't mean RSS isn't useful.  You said yourself that you can already get the functionality you want (question updates emailed to you) by using the RSS feature.  Emailing users individually when they can already subscribe to a feed seems like a waste of time.

Comment: I understand Google only retired their reader, but it is signal they are giving on how they feel about the future of RSS.

Comment: @Gaia No, it's just a signal that they weren't making any money off of Reader. It says nothing at all about RSS.

Comment: I believe that if they felt RSS was important they would have figured out a profitable way to place their ads next to it...

Comment: But back to the original point of the question. Just because they can "already subscribe to a feed" doesn't mean email is a waste of time.

Comment: @Gaia You already have the functionality you're asking for. Implementing email would be a waste of both programmer and processor time.